# Sound from gas fired heater, sounds like rotary equipment

Tags: furnace, central-heating, maintenance

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/hd5TkURAfBc)

I am not very familiar with the system, it's my mom's and my dad used to clean it out and test it every year.  The noise doesn't bother us too much in the house, but I am more concerned with a potential for mechanical failure.  I can't quite make out what the wheel is doing, but if it's a fly wheel for a blower for the gas, I could imagine that it's a rather critical part.

Thoughts on severity?

Comment: Could be a bad/loose bearing or fan.  It is something to check out sooner than later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your blower is going bad

Time to call the repairman, before it destroys whatever parts that are still good.

Comment: Agree, but it's possible to replace blower motor yourself. I just did mine in Spring '21 because it sounded similar.